# How to make gradle build fail when test case fails by changing build.gradle file?

Tags: gradle, testing

I have written test code and build.gradle as the following.
The below test code fails when run but when I type ./gradlew build command, the build is still
successful. I would like to change the contents of build.gradle file to make gradle build fail when test case fails.

test code

```
package com.example.codinghawkwonreview.controller;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockBean;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
import org.springframework.test.context.web.WebAppConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import com.example.codinghawkwonreview.service.UserService;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.post;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(controllers = UserController.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
public class UserControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;
    
    @MockBean
    private UserService userService;

    @Test
    public void 회원가입_컨트롤러_테스트() throws Exception{
        mvc.perform(post("/userRegister")
                .param("userId","dan24")
                .param("userPassword","1")
                .param("userEmail","wbyn122@gmail.com")
                .param("userName","1"))
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk())
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.content().string("<h1>회원 가입에 성공 하셨습니다!</h1>\n"));
    }

}
```

build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.1.1'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.0'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

java {
    sourceCompatibility = '17'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

test{
    include 'com/example/codinghawkwonreview/controller/UserControllerTest.class'
    ignoreFailures(false)
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
    implementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-jpa', version: '3.1.2'
    //mysql-connector-java
    implementation group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '8.0.28'
    //thymeleaf
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

As shown above, I put ignoreFailures(false) inside the test block.
I would like to know how to change the contents of build.gradle file to make gradle build fail
when test case fails and make gradle build successful only when every test case succeeds.